# View file is not calling properly on remote server in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hello friends I am fresher in cakephp. I have created a website in cakephp that is working fine in localhost. But when I uploaded this site to remote server. Its view file not calling properly. Controller functions are calling properly with change of url, but view file not calling according to controller action.
Please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: When you ask a question, it's often beneficial to include some actual detail about the problem you're having.  Without even a tiny bit of code, or error text, or literally anything except a vague description of your problem, you're not likely going to get an answer.

Comment: How about case sensitive file names?

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I found answer. It is basically problem of IIS server where I have to use web.confg file.After  using this my problem resolved.